# Youtube video freezes in Lubuntu 11.04

Tags: 11.04, flash, lubuntu, youtube

*What happens* :

(1) video freezes after a few seconds of idling while audio remains intact.

(2) video resumes if I move the mouse.

---

*What I tried* :

(1) `right click on a video -> "settings" -> uncheck "enable hardware acceleration"`

(2) Chromium. (I usually use Firefox.)

(3) `sudo pm-powersave false`

(4) removed and reinstalled flash plug-in.

`sudo apt-get autoremove flashplugin-installer`

`sudo apt-get autoremove flashplugin-nonfree`

`sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`

(5) installed [Flash-Aid](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-aid/) and used it. (Both stable and beta options.)

No improvement so far.

---

*UPDATE (More Info)* :

`sudo lshw -c display`

```
*-display:0             
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (primary)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
   configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
   resources: irq:44 memory:f0000000-f00fffff memory:d0000000-dfffffff ioport:1800(size=8)
*-display:1 UNCLAIMED
   description: Display controller
   product: Mobile GM965/GL960 Integrated Graphics Controller (secondary)
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 2.1
   bus info: pci@0000:00:02.1
   version: 03
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm bus_master cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:f0100000-f01fffff
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lubuntu is by design a light-weight desktop environment with no compositor installed.

Flash I think requires some-sort of compositor to be present.

Suggestion would be to install the lightweight compositor such as `xcompmgr` and test this to see if Flash works correctly.

**to install**

```
sudo apt-get install xcompmgr
```

Then to test - open a terminal and run

```
nohup xcompmgr &
```

The `nohup` and `&` is important to run xcompmgr in the background including after the terminal has closed.

**to run the xcompmgr from login**

If xcompmgr works then you may wish to consider running this from login.

To do this first create the autostart folder if it doesnt already exist:

```
mkdir -p ~/.config/autostart
```

Then create a xcompmgr desktop file

```
lxshortcut -o ~/.config/autostart/xcompmgr.desktop
```

[image]

logout and login.

N.B. this picture shows what the `xcompmgr.desktop` file contains as well how to confirm `xcompmgr` is running.

[image]

Comment: I've tidied the solution with also a "how to" confirm that xcompmgr is running after login.

Comment: It worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 1):

Install xcompmgr from a command line with:

> sudo apt-get install xcompmgr

Open "Default Applications for LX Session" from the Preferences menu.

On the Composite Manager section, choose the 'Other' option where it says Command. Then enter the following in the box next to it:

> xcompmgr

or, for a little bling:

> xcompmgr -c -C -t-5 -l-5 -r4.2 -o.55

or, another bling-y one:

> xcompmgr -cfF -t-9 -l-11 -r9 -o.95 -D6

Check the man page to work out all the options.

Then just set Autostart to true, Apply and Reload